# Template renders the same information for every user Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

My website has a feature where users can look at each other's profile pages, but at the moment, I have a problem where the currently logged in user's information is being displayed across all the profile pages.

This is the code for the views.py view_profile

```py
def view_profile(request,pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        user = request.user
    args = {'user':user}
    return render(request,'mainapp/profile.html')
```

And here are the urls.py

```py
path('profile/',views.view_profile,name='view_profile'),
    path('profile/<pk>/',views.view_profile,name='view_profile_with_pk'),
```

And here is the `UserProfileInfo` model

```py
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',
                                           processors=[ResizeToFill(150, 150)],
                                           default='default.jpg',
                                           format='JPEG',
                                           options={'quality': 60})
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,default=timezone.now)
    verified = models.BooleanField( default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have tried all sorts of things including switching different things around etc.

So for the rest of the code that is relevant to this problem, here is the actual template that is rendering this information

```html
{% extends 'mainapp/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<p>{{ user }}</p>
<p>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p><br>
<p>{{ user.email }}</p><br>
<p>{{ user.userprofileinfo.description }}</p><br>
<img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.userprofileinfo.image.url }}">

{% endblock %}
```

The result that I wanted was for the user to be able to look at other people's pages and view the other users details, not their own. At the moment, the currently logged in user's details are the only ones being displayed at all, however I want it so that the profile displays information the owner of the profile gives

Thank you for any help, and just let me know if you need any clarification on anything or more code :)

Comment: Seem like you miss context in render function `args = {'user':user}
    return render(request,'mainapp/profile.html', context=args)`

Comment: I also recommend that you should use another name for the context keyword. `user` might lead to some misunderstanding or confusing, because by default, Django use `user` to store current user.

Comment: Ok it's working now, however how would I go about displaying the description text for each individual user? I am a bit confused by that. It works for the ```first_name``` and ```last_name``` because they're apart of the built in User model, but how would I do it for my own custom one?

Comment: I highly recommend you to use *type* in your URL  `path('profile/<int:pk>/',views.view_profile,name='view_profile_with_pk'),
`

Comment: Is there any issue with this one `<p>{{ user.userprofileinfo.description }}</p><br>`? I think it works

Comment: Oh wait it does work lol. I just didn't have any data there for the user I was looking at